# Installing MinGW-W64

Tags: opencv, go, mingw-w64

In the installation instructions for Windows at [GoCV](https://gocv.io/getting-started/windows/) we've the below line:

```
Download and run the MinGW-W64 compiler installer from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/?source=typ_redirect.
```

I downloaded the mentioned file, but could not find executor file, and could not find anything like `x86_64-7.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2` as mentioned in the instuctions, any help?

Comment: The "mentioned file" is a web page. What did you download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of MinGW-w64 is simple. Either download the installer from

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe

or the appropriate package (as a 7-zip archive) directly:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/7.3.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-7.3.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0.7z/download

Some people (including me) experienced random connection problems with the installer at some point, so the second options might be more straightforward.